# Covering a poset by minimum number of chains and antichains

Tags: co.combinatorics, posets

Covering a poset by minmum number of chains is given by [Dilworth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem) and covering a poset by minimum number of antichains is given by [Mirsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirsky%27s_theorem). I was wondering what happens if we allow both chains and antichains.

That is, if a poset $P$ is a union of $s$ chains and $t$ antichains, then what can be said about the minimum value of $s+t$?

Currently I am only aware of the upper bound $2\sqrt{|P|}$ (which apparently is a corollary of the Greene-Kleitman duality theory) but I am more interested in the lower bounds on $s+t$. References, if any, on the above problem will be helpful. I would also be interested in any results for some special class of posets, if  the general problem is difficult.

Comment: Taking a disjoint union of chains of sizes $1,2,\dots,k$ gives the asymptotic lower bound $\sqrt{2|P|}$.

Comment: @RichardStanley: Thanks. I believe your claim is that at least $k$ chains/antichains are required to cover the poset you mentioned. Could you please provide an argument to prove this?

Comment: Removing any chain or antichain from the $k$th Richard Stanley poset gives you something that contains an isomorphic copy of the $(k-1)$th Richard Stanley poset. By induction, you need to remove at least $k$ chains/antichains to get down to the empty poset.

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher, this is exactly the argument I would give.